# Trying to make it so when i click on my windows forms button, the next 3 numbers from my textfile are shown

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the code below.

I am trying to make it so that when I click on the nextButton button it cycles to the next 3 numbers in my textfile. I cant figure out ow, what i have here should work :[

```
namespace GPSProject
{
    class dataPoints
    {
        public int Count { get { return Points.Count; } }
        List<dataPoint> Points;
        //string p;

        public dataPoints(/*string path*/)
        {
            Points = new List<dataPoint>();
           // p = path;
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(/*p*/"C:/Test.txt");
            string input;
            while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] bits = input.Split(',');
                dataPoint a = new dataPoint(bits[0], bits[1], bits[2]);
                Points.Add(a);                
            }

            tr.Close();
        }          



        internal dataPoint getItem(int p)
        {
            if (p < Points.Count)
            {
                return Points[p];
            }
            else

                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Above is the class that breaks down the textfile into inidividual numbers.

```
namespace GPSProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int count;
        internal dataPoints myDataPoints;
        public Form1()
        {
            myDataPoints = new dataPoints();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {




                 count++;
                    if (count == (myDataPoints.Count))
                    {
                        count = 0;
                    }



                dataPoint a = myDataPoints.getItem(count);
                textBoxLatitude.Text = a.CurLatitude;
                textBoxLongtitude.Text = a.CurLongtitude;
                textBoxElevation.Text = a.CurElevation;


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the Windows form
    namespace GPSProject
    {
        class dataPoint
        {
            private string latitude;
            private string longtitude;
            private string elevation;

```
        public dataPoint()         //Overloaded incase no value available
        {
            latitude = "No Latitude Specified";
            longtitude = "No Longtitude Specified";
            elevation = "No Elevation Specified";

        }

        public dataPoint(string Latitude, string Longtitude, string Elevation)
        {

            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.latitude = Latitude;
            this.longtitude = Longtitude;
            this.elevation = Elevation;

        }

        public string CurLongtitude { get { return this.longtitude; } }

        public string CurLatitude { get { return this.latitude; } }

        public string CurElevation { get { return this.elevation; } }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the class the holds the numbers. The numbers i am trying to get the textboxes to show are cycles of CurLongtitude/Latitue/Elevation

Comment: Can you add some details what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be to create a proper vessle for your data: the DataPoint Entity:

```
class DataPoint
{
    // Option 1: Field + read only property
    private string _latitude;
    public string Latitude { get { return _latitude; } }

    // Option 2: Property + compiler generated field
    public string Longitude { get; private set; }
    public string Elevation { get; private set; }

    // Constructor
    public DataPoint(string latitude, string longtitude, string elevation)
    {
        // Internally in this class we use fields
        _latitude = latitude;

        // Unless we use property option 2
        this.Longitude = longitude;
        this.Elevation = elevation; 
    }
}
```

Next we could add a static method to the DataPoint class to load the data points from disk:

```
public static List<DataPoint> LoadFromFile (string filename) 
{
    // The .NET framework has a lot of helper methods
    // be sure to check them out at MSDN

    // Read the contents of the file into a string array
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    // Create the result List
    List<DataPoint> result = new List<DataPoint>();

    // Parse the lines
    for (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] bits = line.Split(',');

        // We're using our own constructor here
        // Do watch out for invalid files, resulting in out-of-index Exceptions
        DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(bits[0], bits[1], bits[2]);
        result.Add(dataPoint);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now that we have all the building blocks. Let's make the application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _index;
    private List<DataPoint> _dataPoints;

    public Form1()
    {
        // Since this is a simple test application we'll do the call here
        _dataPoints = DataPoint.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Test.txt");

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cycle the data points
        _index++;
        if (_index == _dataPoints.Count)
        {
            _index = 0;
        }

        // Get the specific data point
        DataPoint dataPoint = _dataPoints[_index];

        // The empty texts are UI only, so we could check them here
        if (dataPoint.Latitude == null || dataPoint.Latitude == "")
        {
            textBoxLatitude.Text = "No Latitude Specified";
        }
        else
        {
            textBoxLatitude.Text = dataPoint.Latitude;
        }

        // A shorter, inline version
        textBoxLongtitude.Text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataPoint.Longitude) ? "No Longitude Specified" : dataPoint.Longitude;

        // Or if we don't care about empty texts
        textBoxElevation.Text = dataPoint.Elevation;
    }
}
```

Of course there are lots of ways to make the code even shorter, or to use modern techniques like LINQ, but I've tried not to go too far from your existing code. I haven't tried the code, I typed it here on SO :)

Also please be careful in how you format your code. Proper casing and following standards makes your code a lot easier to read by others.

MSDN has a lot of good examples and extensive documentation on the .NET Framework classes.